# Parse email and get number from body

Tags: python, regex, email

I want to extract the first number found in an e-mail body. With the help with email library I extracted just the body from the mail to a string. But the problem is that before the real plain-text body begins there is some info about encoding and such (those contains digits). How can I skip those on a reliable way that is undependent on which client that created the e-mail and just ge the first number.

If I do a

```
match = re.search('\d+', string, re.MULTILINE)
```

It will get the first match in the info about encoding or something and not in the actual mail content.

Ok. I add a sample. This is how it could look (i will extract 123). But I suppose it could look different went sent from another client.

```
--14dae93404410f62f404b2e65e10
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

Junk 123 Junk

--14dae93404410f62f404b2e65e10
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<p>Junk 123 Junk</p>

--14dae93404410f62f404b2e65e10--
```

---

**Update:**
Now I'm stuck with the iterator :-/ I really tried. But I don't get it. This code:

```
msg = email.message_from_string(raw_message)
for part in email.iterators.typed_subpart_iterator(msg, 'text', 'plain'):
    print part
```

outputs:

```
--14dae93404410f62f404b2e65e10
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

Junk 123 Junk

--14dae93404410f62f404b2e65e10
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<p>Junk 123 Junk</p>

--14dae93404410f62f404b2e65e10--
```

Why won't it just output:

```
Junk 123 Junk
```

?

Comment: Well apparently you need to provide us with some sample we can work with.

Comment: Your right, This is one way it could look...

Comment: Use body_line_iterator instead to skip subpart headers. I'll add a concrete example to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to use the iterators to skip over the subpart headers.

http://docs.python.org/library/email.iterators.html#module-email.iterators

This example will print the body of each message subpart that is text/plain:

```
for part in email.iterators.typed_subpart_iterator(msg, 'text', 'plain'):
   for body_line in email.iterators.body_line_iterator(part):
       print body_line
```

Comment: Oh, that seems to be the right way to do it. I will try tomorrow night and see if it's working :)

Comment: I took a while for me to get it working because I only fetched the body with imaplib. Thanks"!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
match = re.search(r"Content-Type:.*?[\n\r]+\D*(\d+)", subject)
if match:
    result = match.group(1)
```

**Explanation:**

```
"
Content-Type:    # Match the characters “Content-Type:” literally
.                # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *?               # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
[\n\r]           # Match a single character present in the list below
                    # A line feed character
                    # A carriage return character
   +                # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\D               # Match a single character that is not a digit 0..9
   *                # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(                # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \d               # Match a single digit 0..9
      +                # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
"
```

Comment: I suppose that will work for my sample, but will it be failsage depending on which client sent the message?

Comment: @NiclasNilsson It will work as long as there is a Content-Type: some blank line and no other digit sequence before. I would go with the other solutions though :)

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. But maybe I get to upset with Python email library that I just use regexp anyway. It's for a hobby project of mine.